# Machine gun with multiple firing modes

Tags: beginner, ruby

I have a class 'M249' it is initiated with 'ammo'
The class has one responsibility(I hope) to expend ammo.
Does there exist a way to increment without accessor or writer?

I am shaky on when I should be using mixins, or inheritance. I think module is best here?

```
module MG_tools
  Rof = {:sustained => rand(3..9), :rapid => rand(5..9), :cyclic => 
rand(1..200), :cease => 0}
end

class M249 
include MG_tools
  attr_accessor :ammo
  def initialize( ammo )
    @ammo = ammo
  end

  def fire(command)
    self.ammo -= Rof[command]
    raise ArgumentError.new("Out of Ammo!") if self.ammo < 1 
  end
end
command = :sustained
gunner = M249.new(200)

loop do 
case gunner::ammo
  when (200..1000)
   command = :cyclic
  when (100..199)
   command = :rapid
  when (6..99)
   command = :sustained
  when (1..5)
   command = :cease
end
    puts "#{command.upcase} FIRE"
    break if command == :cease
    gunner.fire(command)
    puts "*MACHINE GUN NOISES*"
    puts "SAW: #{gunner::ammo} rounds left!"

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a more OOP way of solving your problem.

**Single Responsibility Principle**

I don't think you can quite answer this question without also asking: where the changes are going to come from – and who is going to ask for those changes. In any case I've taken liberties and refactored and refactored to eliminate as many code smells as I code. So this is one way to solve your problem. Notice that there is a class in your gun called “SmartAmmo”. This object knows how to react when ammo goes from 200 to a lesser amount. You will note that each object knows how to act. We are not saying:

```
if ammo == 10 then do_x_y_z # that's a no-no
```

we want to be able to select the appropriate object for the job and we want it to be able to work. the only time we see a conditional is in the "factory method" where they are all created.

Please study this code very carefully, it certainly took some time to get it done for you, and if you feel it is worthy, please promote it so I get some reputation points :)

There is one thing I didn't implement - that is the randomness involved when going from sustainted to rapid to cyclic modes. I've left the implementation of that element of randomness as an exercise for the reader.

I really hope you enjoy the code :)

https://gist.github.com/BKSpurgeon/8774c855926818e2ecd141198273ff47

(It's in a gist because StackOverflow formatting is horrible).

```
class Gun
  attr_reader :smart_ammo

  def initialize(ammo)    
    @smart_ammo = SmartAmmo.at(ammo)
  end

  # how it sounds from start to finish
  def sound_of_the_whole_nine_yards
    sounds_of_gunfire = ""

    loop do
      # concatenate all the shots
      sounds_of_gunfire = sounds_of_gunfire + @smart_ammo.fire
      @smart_ammo = @smart_ammo.next_ammo
      break if @smart_ammo.ammo <= 0
    end

    puts sounds_of_gunfire
  end    
end

class SmartAmmo
  attr_reader :ammo

  def initialize(ammo)
    @ammo = ammo
  end

  def self.at(ammo)
    case ammo
    when 200..1000      
      CyclicAmmo.new(ammo)
    when 100..199      
      RapidAmmo.new(ammo)
    when 6..99            
      SustainedAmmo.new(ammo)
    when (1..5)      
      CeaseAmmo.new(ammo)
    else
      SmartAmmo.new(ammo)
    end
  end

  def next_ammo
    SmartAmmo.at(quantity_remaining_inventory)
  end

  def fire
      "#{speed}" + "#{output_remaining_inventory_after_consumption}"    
  end

  def speed
  end

  def quantity_remaining_inventory
  end

  def output_remaining_inventory_after_consumption    
    "SAW: #{quantity_remaining_inventory} rounds left!\n"       
  end
end

class CyclicAmmo < SmartAmmo
  def speed
    "CYCLIC FIRE\n" + "*MACHINE GUN NOISES*\n"    
  end

  def quantity_remaining_inventory
    @ammo - 5
  end
end

class RapidAmmo < SmartAmmo
  def speed
    "RAPID FIRE\n" + "*MACHINE GUN NOISES*\n"    
  end

  def quantity_remaining_inventory
     @ammo - 8
  end
end

class SustainedAmmo < SmartAmmo
  def speed
    "SUSTAINED FIRE\n" + "*MACHINE GUN NOISES*\n"    
  end

  def quantity_remaining_inventory
     @ammo - 4
  end
end

class CeaseAmmo < SmartAmmo
  def speed
    "CEASE FIRE\n"
  end

  def quantity_remaining_inventory
     -1
  end

  def output_remaining_inventory_after_consumption    
  end
end

Gun.new(200).sound_of_the_whole_nine_yards
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more code / context it is hard to give much of an answer, but a few comments:

- You can make `ammo` a read only attribute by using `attr_reader :ammo` then inside the class or module you can access it using `@ammo` just like you do in your initializer.
- Don't over-complicate your code. Given what you have now there is no reason to do any of what you want. Wait till your code gets complicated enough that you need to break it up then you won't just be guessing what the best option is.
- Consider using delegation rather than inheritance or modules. So your gun could have an `ammo_clip` attribute referencing an `AmmoClip` instance.
- This code:

  ```
  Rof = {:sustained => rand(3..9), :rapid => rand(5..9), 
         :cyclic => rand(1..200), :cease => 0}
  ```

probably doesn't do what you expect. Those random numbers will be calculated once at program startup, not each time a gun is fired.

Comment: I thought it bad practice to access instance variables that way

        def fire(command)
           @ammo -= Rof[command]
           raise ArgumentError.new("Out of Ammo!") if self.ammo < 1 

 Referencing an instance of an object that holds ammunition seems very ideal rather than a module or inheritance.

I am unaware of how to fix the Rof hash
I had it in my original post that I am unsure of how to make those numbers unique to each fire. I know this is a seperate issue/question

My loop / case statement were meant to be a 'test' not functional code
I am very new to tdd/ood